# Please help me improve this question, perhaps by suggesting drastic edits if minor edits will not suffice

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, specific-question, vote-to-close

[On the strategy of comparing parents to supervisors/bosses/employers](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/40955/on-the-strategy-of-comparing-parents-to-supervisors-bosses-employers)

It seems to be closed 'because this is not a question about parenting', but, ostensibly, i'm asking about parenting strategies. I'm really confused.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be asking for a discussion - this is not a discussion forum, it is a fairly strict kind of question and answer site, so you need to provide a well-formed, on-topic question that has a definitive answer we can give.

I don't think edits will be sufficient, the basic premise doesn't match what Stack Exchange is set up to do.

Have a good read of our help pages and look at highly upvoted questions and answers - that should give you an idea how the site works.